# AngularJS resetting array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I asked a question similar to this and tried the solution that worked previously with no luck. Pretty simple problem. I have the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', ['appControllers']);
"use strict";
var appControllers = angular.module('app', []);
appControllers.controller('personController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.responses = [[], [], []];

$scope.addCoach = function() {
$scope.responses[0].push($scope.coach.name);
};
$scope.addAthlete = function() {
$scope.responses[1].push($scope.athlete.name);
};
$scope.addSupportStaff = function() {
$scope.responses[2].push($scope.employee.name);
};
```

So basically I'm trying to add a list of coaches, athletes and supporting staff to the respective arrays within the array but when I check the console log of my $scope.responses it only shows the most recently added one.

EDIT:

So I've changed my code to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', ['appControllers']);
"use strict";
var appControllers = angular.module('app', []);
appControllers.controller('personController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.responses = {
coaches: [],
athletes: [],
employees: []   
};

$scope.addCoach = function() {
$scope.responses.coaches.push($scope.coach.name); 
console.log($scope.responses);
$scope.coach = {}; // Do this to clean up the form fields
};

$scope.addAthlete = function() {
$scope.responses.athletes.push($scope.athlete.name); 
console.log($scope.responses);
$scope.athlete = {}; // Do this to clean up the form fields
};

$scope.addSupportStaff = function() {
$scope.responses.employees.push($scope.employee.name); 
console.log($scope.responses);
$scope.employee = {}; // Do this to clean up the form fields
};
```

}]);

HTML

```
<h1>Coaches Attending</h1>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="personController">
<div>
<div>
<input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="coach.name">
<button type="button" ng-click="addCoach()">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>   </div>
<div >
    <ul><li ng-repeat="coach in responses.coaches">{{coach}}</li></ul>
</div>
</div>

<br>  
<h1>Athletes Attending</h1>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="personController">
<div>
<div>
<input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="athlete.name">
<button type="button" ng-click="addAthlete()">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>   </div>
<div >
    <ul><li ng-repeat="athlete in responses.athletes">{{athlete}}</li></ul>
</div>
</div>

<br>  
<h1>Support Staff Attending</h1>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="personController">
<div>
<div>
<input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="employee.name">
<button type="button" ng-click="addSupportStaff()">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>   </div>
<div >
    <ul><li ng-repeat="employee in responses.employees">{{employee}}</li></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

But my problem now is that when I add someone in the coach column after adding any in athlete or support staff, it removes the previous entries.

Comment: Question title refers to resetting the array, which is confusing as the code and your text don't seem to have anything to do with resetting an array. Can you post more code or a fiddle? There's not enough here to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I was defining the controller and app multiple time giving it multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an object instead?

```
$scope.responses = {
    coaches: [],
    athletes: [],
    employees: []   
};
```

And then something like:

```
$scope.addCoach = function (contact) {
    $scope.responses.coaches.push(contact.name);
};

var exampleCoach = {name: "Tim Burns", email: "test@tester.com"};
$scope.addCoach(exampleCoach);
console.log($scope.responses);
```

If that doesn't help, setup a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) with your entire related code, including the views. Might be something wrong with how you are displaying the results.

**[Edit:]** With your problem where the data is cleared, it's because you're pushing a reference. So when you update the original, the reference is cleared as well. You need to make a copy of the object when you're pushing it.

Try something like this:

```
$scope.addCoach = function (contact) {
    var clonedContact= angular.copy(contact);
    $scope.responses.coaches.push(clonedContact);
};
```

Comment: see I had this setup at first and everything was gravy but I figured I was using an object to store just strings of names so why not just switch an array of strings.

Comment: Because your `responses` array is defined in a determined structure that will never change. So why have it as an array with int key/indexes, when they have a clear purpose. Using an object would communicate better in your code.

Comment: @Bobby Updated my answer. You need to use `angular.copy(coach)`.